# Guternberg module not showhing on drupal 9

Tags: drupal, project-gutenberg

I'm using drupal 9 and I want to use gutenberg a page builder, to make it easy for my co-worker who don't know anything about code.
The thing is that I completed the installation but the edito isn't showing. I don't understand why. I try all the settings.

[image: 1]

I want to know why Gutenberg editor isn't working and I want the editor to be visible.

Comment: have you tried to clear the cache after the setup?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Yes I cleared the cache